# how to make the last layer's nodes spread evenly in vertical direction?

Tags: tree, echarts

In a family tree, as below, the gaps between the nodes are even in the same vertical layer except the last one, how to make the last layer's nodes have the same effect, i.e., the same gap/height between the nodes?

[image]